# How to bring typeeffect on Whatsapp cloud API

Tags: whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

I'm working on a product that involves a lot of calculations before sending a response back to the user. As a result, there is a long delay, and the user often follows up with multiple messages asking, "Hey, is this working?"

If there is a way to simulate a typing effect, I believe I can reduce this situation.

Is there any way to achieve this?